# Unable to login into web application with Identity Core (custom identity), but username/password are correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm sorry for this long question.
I've a web application who uses Identity AspNET Core. For some reason, my web application does not have the "registration", but only the login. That's because the users registration will be done by another web application. So I must use a custom context who contains this users information:

```
public partial class CustomersInformationDBContext : IdentityDbContext<Customer>
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity => {
                entity.ToTable("Customers", "dbo");
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Email })
                    .HasName("PK_Customers");
                entity.Ignore(e => e.LockoutEnd);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.Id);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.AccessFailedCount);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.LockoutEnabled);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.PasswordHash);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.EmailConfirmed);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.PhoneNumber);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.ConcurrencyStamp);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.SecurityStamp);
                entity.Ignore(e => e.TwoFactorEnabled);
            });
        }
```

`Customer` is the `IdentityUser`:

```
public partial class Customer : IdentityUser
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? Password { get; set; }
        public string TempPassword { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? NormalizedUsername { get; set; } //Caps lock Username
        public string? NormalizedEmail { get; set; } //Caps lock email
    }
```

So `Customer` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](320) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TempPassword] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [NormalizedUsername] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Email] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

In `Login.cshtml.cs` there is the `OnPostAsync` method, in which I've added the following lines:

```
returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/Customer/HomeProducts");            
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email); //I've added this line            
            var result4 = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password); //this line returns FALSE
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Username, user.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false); //This line return FAILED. user.Username and user.Password are correct.
```

While debuggin, `result` always return Failed, even if the credentials are correct!

Maybe this custom Identity misses something that is mandatory, but I can't figure out what is missing.

In my `Program.cs` I've added:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<Customer>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    
})
 //.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
 .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<Customer>>()
 .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
 //.AddDefaultUI() 

.AddEntityFrameworkStores<CustomersAdminSite.ModelScaffolding.CustomersInformationDBContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
});
```

Can you help me please? Thank you
(sorry for my bad english).

I want to successfully login into my web application because credentials are correct

Comment: does await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email); actually find a user or is it null?

Comment: Hi @jeb, after var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email); useris not null! and Username, email, password fields contain the correct values!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Identity `UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync()` usually hashes the password given and compares to the `PasswordHash` column stored in the database.

Your code shows that you're overriding the `Customer` entity (based on the `IdentityUser`) to "ignore", i.e. not persist the `PasswordHash` field to the database.

I see you've added your own `Password` and `TempPassword` columns, but I can't see anywhere that you're configuring `UserManager` to use those fields (if that's even an option).

So I'm assuming `CheckPasswordAsync()` is returning false because it can't find the PasswordHash field.  I'm slightly surprised it doesn't throw an exception in that case.

Comment: Hi @Chris Denning thanks for you reply, but i've made a decision: use the default Idneitty environmente, without cutomization. It is so hard to me to customize